# root is unable to find flutter command

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, root

when I run the flutter doctor command or other flutters command on ubuntu  it works fine..
but when I switch to root user with

```
sudo su
```

then I run

```
flutter doctor
```

then it throws an Error

```
Command 'flutter' not found, but can be installed with:
snap install flutter
```

I don't know why this happening can some one help me to find actual problem thanks in advance ..

Comment: Have you checked these [procedures](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) for the path?

Comment: yes.. i have added the path in .bashrc file

Comment: and working fine without root  when i switch to root user it gives error

Comment: Now that I realize you are using root, by default the user's bashrc is not accessed by the root, protection mechanism, you will have to create a specific bashrc for root. In this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/268460/wheres-bashrc-for-root) he talks about bashrc for root.

Comment: thank You bro.. got it.. its really helped me now I've added same path of flutter in root bashrc file now its running thank you for responding !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Chance helped me to add flutter path in root bashrc file
i have added flutters path in /etc/bash.bashrc file and now its working in root user also.. thx again @Chance